# finding the matrix representation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

i was having hard time solving this one, any help will be greatly appreciated:

given the following linear transformation:
$$
T(X) := BX^t-XB^t
$$
$$
B= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
find $[T]_E$

where $E=(E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)$
$$
E_1= \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right);\ E_2= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right);\  E_3= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right);\  E_4= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Compute $T(E_j)$ for each $j \in \{1,2,3,4 \}$ and then put them in terms of your basis $E$, that is find $\alpha_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
T(E_j) = \alpha_{1,j}\cdot E_1 + \alpha_{2,j} \cdot E_2 + \alpha_{3,j} \cdot E_3+\alpha_{4,j} \cdot E_4
$$
The $\alpha_{i,j}$ will be the coefficients of the matrix $[T]_{E}$, which will be a $4 \times 4$ real matrix.

---

**Example T(E1):** By the definition of $T$ we obtain that
\begin{align}
 T(E_1) & = BE^t_1 - E_1B^t \\
 & = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)^t - \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) ^t \\ 
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \\ 
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)\\
&  = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \\
& = 0 \cdot E_1 + 0 \cdot E_2 + 0 \cdot E_3+ 0 \cdot E_4
 \end{align}

**Example T(E4):** Again by the definition of $T$ we obtain that
\begin{align}
 T(E_4) &  = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)^t - \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) ^t \\ 
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \\ 
& = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)\\
&  = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        -1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right) \\
& = 0 \cdot E_1 + 1 \cdot E_2 + -1 \cdot E_3+ 0 \cdot E_4
 \end{align}

**Partial Matrix** So until now we have the coefficients of the first and the fourth column, then $[T]_E$ will look like 
$$
[T]_E = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & \alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,3} & 0 \\
        0 & \alpha_{2,2} &\alpha_{2,3} & 1\\
        0 & \alpha_{3,2} &\alpha_{3,3} &-1\\
        0 & \alpha_{4,2} &\alpha_{4,3} & 0\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
Observe that since $E_1$ is represented by $e_1=(1,0,0,0)$ and $E_4$ by $e_4=(0,0,0,1)$ then indeed 
$$
[T]_E \cdot e_1= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & \alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,3} & 0 \\
        0 & \alpha_{2,2} &\alpha_{2,3} & 1\\
        0 & \alpha_{3,2} &\alpha_{3,3} &-1\\
        0 & \alpha_{4,2} &\alpha_{4,3} & 0\\
        \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)\\
[T]_E \cdot e_4= \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & \alpha_{1,2} & \alpha_{1,3} & 0 \\
        0 & \alpha_{2,2} &\alpha_{2,3} & 1\\
        0 & \alpha_{3,2} &\alpha_{3,3} &-1\\
        0 & \alpha_{4,2} &\alpha_{4,3} & 0\\
        \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
As shown in both examples. I assume you can now take it form here to complete $[T]_E$

Comment: hey can you show me example on how to compute e1?

Comment: Yes sure, give some time to make an edit.

Comment: thanks! and wouldnt it be a 2x2 matrix? if u add up all the sub matrices?

Comment: Done. And it is simpler to see $[T]_E$ as a $4 \times 4$ real matrix who acts on $4 \times 1$ real vectors, since each real $2 \times 2$ matrix can be seen as a $4 \times 1$ vector, as shown with $E_1$ in my answer.